# Bad pointer returned by [NSDate distantPant]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Why does this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Foundation/NSDate.h>
int main() {
    printf("%p\n", [NSDate distantPast]);
    return 0;
}
```

return a bad pointer on 64-bit machines? (0xc22d63c8c500000d in my case)

Comment: How do you know it's bad?

Comment: Because if I try to inspect the memory from gdb (x/32x <pointer>) I get a 'Cannot access memory at address 0x...' error.

Comment: It is **tagged pointer**, as the address is an *odd* number (`...000d`). Dereferencing odd address into anything other than `char` will segfault (or maybe bus error) and dump core. Tagged pointer stores information in the pointer itself.

Comment: distantPant always returns bad pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *tagged pointer* - these have the least significant bit set and the other bits contain the type and value. They provide a compact representation for certain types which avoids memory allocation. For more details see [Mike Ash's blog article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html)